Car parts product import discussion
Now regarding car parts. I'm not coder to be clear.
We are selling genuine car parts, all that we have is price-lists from distributors. Files are big, 500,000-1,000,000 unique SKU by brand. So - how to import them.
Importing by magento files are not the proper way. Let me explain why.
For example we are importing 1,000,000 sku. Editing with hand 1000 products, updating title, pictures, weights, prices...
Once month or week passes, we have new pricelist. If we will update product by same way we imported it, we will lose everything that we have done with hand while updated the product. Need to avoid this, so this should be something like external database where to control the product?
If someone here have created solution or have idea how to do it. I would like to speak and probably make a deal for help. As by fact we need outsource to solve this problem. Or someone here who have successfully launched car parts store on magento. We need your help.

you need to export existing products and modify that csv file and import it again

Thank you for your answer. May I ask, maybe you know, why my export does not work normally? When I click export data, it does not do anything

if you are using Magento's default export functionality and your Magento version is above 2.4.0 then Magento uses Queue functionality. This means once you click export Magento pushes it to the queue and once your export is ready then it will show on the grid below.
